# Removing/hiding a select option in javascript without making it look awkward (need to delay the native onclick event of the select element)

Tags: javascript, html, delay, html-select

code:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16952797/webdev/uppg1/kontakt.html

http://jsfiddle.net/v8uMJ/ (the result box does not succesfully render the page or reproduce the bug)

relevant code:

```
function addEvent(element, eventType, theFunction, capture)
{
    if(element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, theFunction, capture);
    } 
    else if(element.attachEvent)
    {
       element.attachEvent( "on" + eventType, theFunction);
    }
}

function removeDefaultOption(event)
{
    document.getElementById("selectSuggestion").options[0].style.display = "none";      // <-- looks awkward
    //document.getElementById("selectSuggestion").remove(0);                                            // <-- also looks awkward and needs boundaries so that all options don't get removed after each click
    //delay(1000);                                                                                                                  // <-- tried delaying the thread but it didn't work..
    //setInterval(function(){},1000);                                                                                   // <-- tried delaying the thread but it didn't work..
}

function addEventListeners()
{
...
    addEvent(document.getElementById("selectSuggestion"), "click", removeDefaultOption, false);
}
```

context: So what I'm trying to do is whenever you click on the select element in the suggestion form (swe: Förslag) I want the first option (value: --Välj Förslag--) to disappear from the list. The problem is that the options are displayed "too fast" so I either need to a) delay the displaying of the options after setting the style.display of the first option or b) I need to prevent the default event of clicking on select and then override it with my own function so I can control when it should be run (I don't know the name of the native function that is run when you click on the select element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "focus" event instead of the "click" event. This fires the function direclty when it's in focus instead of "waiting" for the click to be completed.

Cleaned JS-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhS3p/1/

```
document.getElementById("selectSuggestion").addEventListener("focus", removeDefaultOption, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, works perfectly!
In addition to your jsfiddle I'll add my own implementation for reference (note that I've added new functionality to the suggestion form, unrelated to the solution of this bug): http://jsfiddle.net/vaGn3/

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the option you want like so:

```
var index = 0;
var select =  document.getElementById("selectSuggestion");
select.removeChild(select[index]);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLOptionsCollection> has no method 'splice', I think I gotta typecast it or something?
(sorry for late reply, was afk)

Comment: @Ryuji -- Changed my answer, try that out.,

Comment: Tried it, the visual glitch persists though.
It's basically the same thing as the following (which didn't work either):
document.getElementById("selectSuggestion").remove(0); The problem is that the onclick event of the select element fires before the options are properly modified, leading to a visual glitch.